# Check the width of all images and set new width if over a certain size

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a page with several images that have the same class ".bestsell-thumb" . How can I make all these images into an array, then get each ones width and if it's greater than 80px change it to 80px?

I tried this

```
var  bsThumb = $(".bestsell-thumb").each(function(){
             $(this).height();
});
```

just to get the heights, but I'm pretty sure I'm way off.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried editing the CSS using the 'max-width' parameter in its class?

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".bestsell-thumb").width(function(i, w) {
    return w > 80 ? 80 : w;
});
```

They do of course have to be loaded before you can get anything!

Comment: Nice function, clean and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".bestsell-thumb").each(function(){
    if ($(this).width() > 80) {
        $(this).css("width", "80px");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$(".bestsell-thumb").each(function(){
    if($(this).width() > 80){
        $(this).width("80px");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS instead of JavaScript:

```
.bestsell-thumb {
  max-width: 80px;
  height: auto; /* maintains proportions */
}
```

You can set `max-height` in the same style block, too -- just set `width: auto` as well.

Comment: this is the simplest way. I didn't realize there was max-height property. Thanks!

Comment: Very welcome. Don't forget to [accept your favorite answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to encourage others to help you in the future.